# Не запускается контейнер в docker?

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi

начал изучать Docker.

Установил docker на raspberri pi 4 model B, по мануалу скачал hello world, контейнер есть и я успешно удалил.
В docker hub нашел официальный apache, делаю pull, вижу что все ок, потом делаю docker ps -a и не вижу самого контейнера......потом решил запулить adguardhome, та же песня.
В docker'е отсутствуют контейнеры...
Потом написал такую команду docker container ls -l и тоже пусто???

Объясните что не так???
Где-то читал, что всему виной bash, мол контейнер есть, но он запускается на доли секунды и отрубается!

docker version

```
raspberrypi:~ $ docker version
    Client: Docker Engine - Community
    Version:           20.10.18
    API version:       1.41
    Go version:        go1.18.6
    Git commit:        b40c2f6
    Built:             Thu Sep  8 23:11:51 2022
    OS/Arch:           linux/arm
    Context:           default
    Experimental:      true
```

Пусто

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
```

Comment: `docker pull` скачивает образ, но контейнер оно не запускает, нужно ещё выполнить `docker run`

Comment: @Exploding Kitten
Спасибо Вам получилось!